# Where can I get a topographical map of Israel / Transjordan?

Tags: old-testament, resource-request, israel, geography

As an aide in Old Testament study, I'm looking for a topographical map of Israel - both East and West of the Jordan. Specifically, I want a map with topographical layer-lines showing specific heights. I'm not looking for one of those "green is lower and brown is higher and mountainous areas look crinkled" maps. I want the most precise and detailed map available. It would also be helpful if this map had major landforms (rivers, mountain peaks, etc.) labeled.

Does anyone know where I can find one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it really does not concern Christian theology or practice.

Comment: @curiousdannii It's a question about studying the Bible - obviously relevant to Christianity. Do you have a better recommendation about where I should put it?

Comment: @Truth - if you find out, please let me know cos I have wanted one for years.  I think the most likely option is to get one from some shop in Israel.  Or maybe someone in the States sells them.

Answer (score 2):

**Where can I get a topographical map of Israel / Transjordan?**

There is https://en-gb.topographic-map.com for free.  Enter say "topographic map Israel" in google.  Though it does not show contour lines it does show the elevation at any point you click on.

For Israel, the writing on the map is in Hebrew, and identifies towns and cities.

I suggest you pick on Jerusalem and zoom in.  You will see the map shows buildings and all.  So Jerusalem is just on a latitude slightly north of the northern edge of the Dead Sea. Latitudes are parallel to the equator.  The Dead Sea and Jordan region is in blue because it is all below sea level, so persevere in finding the northern shore.  the writing for Jeruslaem is larger than other towns of course.  Zoom in on the writing for Jerusalem until you see the outline of buildings.  To the East of the writing is the Muslim "Dome of the Rock" where the Temple once stood.  To the east of that is the Kidron Valley and further east is the Mount of Olives.

Persevere with it and it might meet your needs.

As for hard, paper copies of topographical maps:-

Quick look on google.  And the good news is that you can get maps from stanfords.co.uk .... the bad news is that there is a 4 to 6 month wait because of hot demand, and the even worse news is that each map costs £17.99 and there are between 22 and 26 of them. So assuming you want all of them that's over $500 plus postage.  However, if you know which specific area of Israel/Gaza/West Bank you want then its an option.

More bad news is that the contour lines are at 20 meters on some and 25 meters on others which is about 70 feet or 80 feet on others... perhaps not good enough for the price.

Search for "100k topographic israel" in google.